Issues With Drawing Arc Using Tikz-3dplot
Here is the diagram I drew.

Here is the code used to generate it.
\begin{figure}[!th]
    \centering
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{60}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
        \draw[<->] (-5, 0, 0) -- (5, 0, 0) node[right] {\(x_1\)};
        \draw[<->] (-2.5, -4.33, 0)  -- (2.5, 4.330, 0) node[right] {\(x_2\)};
        \draw[<->, dashed, gray] (0, -5, 0)  -- (0, 5, 0) node[right] {\(x_2\)};
        \draw[->] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, -2.5, 4.33) node[above] {\(x_3\)};
        \draw[<->, dashed, gray] (0, 0, -5)  -- (0, 0, 5) node[right] {\(x_3\)};

        \draw[->, thick, black] (0, 0, 0) -- (3, 0, 0) node[left] {\(\vec{e}_1\)};
        \draw[->, thick, black] (0, 0, 0) -- (1.5, 2.598, 0) node[right] {\(\vec{e}_2\)};
        \draw[->, thick, black] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, -1.5, 2.598) node[left] {\(\vec{e}_3\)};

        \tdplotdrawarc{(0, 0, 0)}{1.5}{0}{60}{anchor=north}{\(60^\circ\)};

        \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{60};
        \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0, 0, 0)}{1.5}{-30}{90}{above right}{\(120^\circ\)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Basis vectors with angles being decided by the new inner product.}
\end{figure}

Now, if I'm not wrong, the angle between $\mathbf{e_3}$ and $\mathbf{e}_2$ should be 120 degrees. So really, everything is fine here.
However, what happens if I rotated the view by a little bit?

The only thing I changed from the code above is that I used \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}. This is not good! Am I overlooking something simple?
EDIT: Here is a compilable extract.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
        \draw[<->] (-5, 0, 0) -- (5, 0, 0) node[right] {\(x_1\)};
        \draw[<->] (-2.5, -4.33, 0)  -- (2.5, 4.330, 0) node[right] {\(x_2\)};
        \draw[<->, dashed, gray] (0, -5, 0)  -- (0, 5, 0) node[right] {\(x_2\)};
        \draw[->] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, -2.5, 4.33) node[above] {\(x_3\)};
        \draw[<->, dashed, gray] (0, 0, -5)  -- (0, 0, 5) node[right] {\(x_3\)};

        \draw[->, thick, black] (0, 0, 0) -- (3, 0, 0) node[left] {\(\vec{e}_1\)};
        \draw[->, thick, black] (0, 0, 0) -- (1.5, 2.598, 0) node[right] {\(\vec{e}_2\)};
        \draw[->, thick, black] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, -1.5, 2.598) node[left] {\(\vec{e}_3\)};

        \tdplotdrawarc{(0, 0, 0)}{1.5}{0}{60}{anchor=north}{\(60^\circ\)};

        \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{60};
        \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0, 0, 0)}{1.5}{-30}{90}{above right}{\(120^\circ\)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Possibly: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300922/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/682705/ or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/679772/? If all else fails, try providing comilable code.

Thank you for the links! I haven't been able to detect what's causing this issue, however. I'm scratching my head here given that I'm following the tikz-3dplot documentation as close as I could. (Well, except for the fact that I'm manually computing and writing in the coordinates instead of defining them!)

I seem to think I remember something about the theta stuff, but it is such a long time since I used this package.
